# Laravel-echo receives events but doesn't join channel listeners

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nginx, socket.io, laravel-echo

To start with, I have a real-time chat app (Vue as frontend, Laravel as backend)
On localhost it works perfectly, but not on production.

I've noticed that I do receive events, but I've never been able to join any channel.
Here is all the information, *I hope you have any ideas on how to solve it. Thanks!*

**Main.js (laravel-echo / socket.io connection):**

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"
window.io = require('socket.io-client')

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: 'https://example.com/socket.io',
    auth: {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
        }
    }
});
```

**Chat component (listener):**

```
window.Echo.private(`chat.${this.user.id}`)
.listen('NewMessage', (e) => {
    console.log(e.message);
});
```

**Nginx config:**

```
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    root /var/www/html/example/api/public/;    
    index index.html index.php;

    location / {
        root /var/www/html/example/web/dist/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /socket.io {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:6001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }

    location /api {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

**Laravel-echo config:**

```
{
    "authHost": "https://example.com/api",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [
        {
            "appId": "xxx",
            "key": "xxxxxxx"
        }
    ],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {},
        "sqlite": {
            "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
        }
    },
    "devMode": true,
    "host": null,
    "port": "6001",
    "protocol": "http",
    "socketio": {},
    "secureOptions": 67108864,
    "sslCertPath": "",
    "sslKeyPath": "",
    "sslCertChainPath": "",
    "sslPassphrase": "",
    "subscribers": {
        "http": true,
        "redis": true
    },
    "apiOriginAllow": {
        "allowCors": true,
        "allowOrigin": "*",
        "allowMethods": "GET, POST",
        "allowHeaders": "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Authorization, X-CSRF-TOKEN, X-Socket-Id"
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you please check if echo is using wss or ws in production? Note that you don't have ssl configured in production

Comment: @MHIdea SSL is configured and I've already tried using laravel-echo through https `https://localhost:6001`, but the result was the same

Comment: How do I check weather it's using wss or ws?

Comment: just check network tab in browser developer tools. How did you implement server side socket.io?

Comment: @MHIdea I don't have ANY errors and it looks like it should work properly, but it doesn't work. All it shows are events, but I guess the problem is that it doesn't authenticate users

Comment: You can check **Main.js (laravel-echo / socket.io connection)** (above, in the question description)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's working in local but not in production, you need to check if ***socket.io*** path on your domain is proxied to laravel echo server. To check this path run this path in browser and it must return an array. if it's not proxied you will be redirected according to laravel rules.

```json
https://example.com/socket.io must return:

{"code":0,"message":"Transport unknown"}
```

Comment: At the localhost it just says `Ok`, however, on the prod. server it replies with `Cannot GET /socket.io`

Comment: How do you think we can change nginx proxy so that it starts working properly?

Comment: Hmm.. With your config I can now see `{"code":0,"message":"Transport unknown"}`, however, something's still wrong in my code because the chat is not working in real-time

Comment: https://github.com/mhidea/laravel-echo-nginx/issues/1